# An illustrated children's book about each season being created as a planet by music

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, illustrated-story

I'm trying to find an illustrated book I had as a child. I can't recall the title or illustrator but the general theme was this:

A god like figure with a lute, sitar or harp plays music and creates planets. He plays different notes and creates a planet for each of the four seasons. I recall vividly the Winter planet as a page illustrated with a repeated pattern of silver horses and deer. The Summer planet had a page of pink flamingos and other birds I think! In the end all the planets join to create Earth, but I'm not 100% on that. It was beautiful and really colourful, I'd love to find it. I've tried many different search terms! I seem to think the title had something to do with the name of the music maker, but neither I nor my family can remember what that was.

We had it about 20 years ago and it was in English.

We managed to recover a page from the book whilst searching through some old boxes:

[image]

Comment: Roughly when did you read this book?

Comment: An answer claiming to be posted by the original poster said, "We managed to recover a page from the book whilst searching through some old boxes.If you recognise this book or have any information as to what it might be about, please let me know."  [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm2Dw.jpg)  Adding as a comment because the "answer" is likely to be deleted as not answering the question.  Can't verify the poster's identity, so not editing.